# Plotting a 3D function along a vector

Tags: plotting

Newbie here!

If I have the 3D function (a, b, and c are specified by me),

```
E[a_,b_,c_] := (x+a)^2 + (y+b)^2 + (z+c)^2.
```

How would I go about getting mathematica to plot along some direction, e.g. [100] or [111]?

Basically I want to take a 1D cross-section of a 3D plot.

Edit.
I decided I was too vague about what exactly I need. I need to plot a 3D function from the origin to [1,0,0] and from the origin to [1,1,1]. I then need to put these two graphs on the same 1D graph with the [1,1,1] direction being the traditionally -x direction and the [1,0,0] direction being the traditionally +x direction.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e[pos_, parms_] := SquaredEuclideanDistance[pos, -parms]
parms = {2, 3, 4}; (* Your {a,b,c} *)
Show[Plot[e[{x, 0, 0}, parms], {x, 0, 1}], 
     Plot[e[-{x, x, x}, parms], {x, -1, 0}], 
     PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plotting it dynamically

```
e[pos_, parms_] := SquaredEuclideanDistance[pos, -parms]
Manipulate[ Show[Plot[e[{x, 0, 0}, {a,b,c}], {x, 0, 1}], Plot[e[-{x, x, x}, {a,b,c}], {x, -1, 0}],
                 PlotRange -> Automatic,  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
            {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! You guys both helped. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got the question right but here is what I think you want to do:

The argument v is the vector along which you want to plot your function.

```
f[a_, b_, c_, v_] := (v[[1]] x + a)^2 + (v[[2]] x + b)^2 + (v[[3]] x + c)^2
```

The plot you described could be set up like this

```
Show[
 Plot[f[1, 2, 3, {1, 0, 0}], {x, 0, 1}],
 Plot[f[1, 2, 3, -{1, 1, 1}], {x, -1, 0}],
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You guys both helped. I got it.